# socket.connect() does not throw an exception when nothing bound to host?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcpsocket

Trying to connect to a TCP socket, but have had weird disconnect/reconnect issues. I have stopped anything running on the port user `fuser -k PORT/tcp`, but still see that socket.connect() returns successfully.

Could anyone shed some light as to why this would not throw an Exception on connect()?

```
SERVER_IP = '... an ip address of a real apache server, nothing bound to 2000'
PORT = 2000
new_socket = socket.socket()
new_socket.settimeout(4.0)
try:
    new_socket.connect((SERVER_IP, PORT))
except Exception as e:
    print('unable to connect')
    return # EXPECTED TO RETURN HERE
else:
    new_byte = new_socket.recv(1)
    if len(new_byte) == 0:
        print('empty!') # GET HERE
```

The socket docs suggest that receiving a empty response (`len() == 0`) back would indicate that the host is saying that [it will not send any additional information](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html), but if there's not a TCP socket being hosted on that port, I don't know how that code would ever be reached.

Comment: I have seen this occasionally many years ago on localhost. Was the server running on localhost?

Comment: SERVER_IP is in continent C, Reach EXPECTED from continent A, reach 'GET HERE' from continent B